# Printing the TreeView in WPF using MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, printing, treeview

I have a treeView to return my text search result from text files.

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding FirstGeneration}"
             ...>
  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle.../>
  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PreExp}" />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Exp}"
          FontStyle="{Binding FontStyle}"
          Foreground="{Binding Color}"  />
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding PostExp}" />
      </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

To get the result as a tree (because we get the result from a C++ project as list), we create a logical tree and display the exp in red. I separated them into three textBoxes.

The treeView is in a diffrent UserControl - and I put it into the SearchView (UC).

Now I'd like to print **all** the results on this tree. I prefer that the document is printed with the emphasis on the search result in red.

It looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNUCP.png).

I tried the **PrintDialog.PrintVisual**. The problem is that I can't reach the tree or the search expression because the ViewModel does not know the view etc.

Although I tried it in the code behaind this code below and it prints only what he sees and not the entire tree results.

```
PrintDialog dialog = new PrintDialog();
if (dialog.ShowDialog() != true)
  return;
dialog.PrintVisual(SearchResultTree, "The Search Result Tree");
```

Also I tried the option with **FlowDocument**:

```
FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument();
foreach (SearchObjectViewModel item in tv.Items)
  doc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(item.PreExp+item.Exp+item.PostExp)));
pd.PrintDocument(((IDocumentPaginatorSource)doc).DocumentPaginator,exp);
```

10x 4 helping!

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that I can't reach the tree or the search expression because the ViewModel does not know the view etc.

When using MVVM, the interaction between the View and ViewModel should happen via [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx).
You could map/bind one Property to one UI element; which gets a call back on Set.

Here is one of my example on [mvvm-binding-treeview-item-changed](http://jacobaloysious.wordpress.com/2012/02/19/mvvm-binding-treeview-item-changed-to-icommand/). Hope it is some use.